# Ubuntu machine randomly reboots

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

I have a Ubuntu machine which randomly reboots itself:

```
last reboot
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab12 Sat Mar 25 23:48 - 12:42  (11:53)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab12 Wed Mar 22 18:28 - 12:42 (3+17:14)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab12 Sat Mar 18 05:10 - 12:42 (8+06:32)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab12 Thu Mar 16 13:52 - 12:42 (9+21:49)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab12 Thu Mar 16 09:50 - 13:52  (04:02)
```

I am trying to figure out why and stop it. I pasted the logs to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/Lht2tkkB).

I am not doing these reboots. Also, it seems like there is nothing going on (like a crash, etc.) which would cause the server to reboot.

Comment: @Vlastimil No I don't have physical access, just SSH. And I have no idea what `-- MARK --` is.

Comment: I just read somewhere else: "The --MARK-- messages are added at regular intervals just to indicate that syslogd is still working, even when no other messages are added. "

Comment: @Vlastimil I created a pastebin. If you require more logs just tell me which.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs. Is it a multiuser system and someone else reboots it?

Comment: did you deploy the unattended-updates service and allow it to reboot after updates if it was required by an update?

Comment: @Jan No I am the only user.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I cannot remember doing it. How can I check if it set?

Comment: See if in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` the parameter `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` is set to "true" and if it is uncommented.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann `50unattended-upgrades` does not exist in that directory. I only have `01autoremove  01autoremove-kernels  20changelog  70debconf`

Comment: then I guess unattended-upgrades is not installed? `dpkg -l | grep unattended`

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Yes it isn't installed.

Comment: Your answer could be here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/202335/how-can-i-track-the-cause-of-random-reboots . I'll post the best answer I've seen at that link...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `/proc/sys/kernel/panic`? If it's value is 1 then server will immediately reboot on panic. Bad drivers can cause kernel panic.

If it's not panic, check last issue of reboot, maybe overheating is the issue.

`last reboot`